# How to get range of textField text till 6 characters?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, character, string-length

I've a `UITextField` for entering pincode number.
My requirement is when textField character range reach to 6th character then I've to do server validation and I have to put the data in labels. If character range is less than 5 then I will pass nil value.

**Below is my code :-**

```
//TextField character range
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == pinCode
    {
        guard let text = textField.text else { return  true }

        let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
        if(5 >= newLength)
        {
            print(newLength)
        }

        else
        {
            if newLength == 6
            {
                serverValidation()

                print(textField.text!)
                setFields(city: "Ajmer", state: "Rajasthan", country: "India")
                return newLength <= 6
            }
            else
            {
                 return newLength <= 6
            }
        }

    }

    return true
}
```

**My problem is when (newLength == 6) then I'm getting textField text of 5 characters only. I mean if suppose zip code is 560068 then text I'm getting  56006 only. (But I've to do server validation in that condition only for 6 characters zip code)**

So if (newLength == 6) then how can I get 6 characters in text field, and then I can do server validation here only.

I'm new in swift.

Thanks

Comment: This is BEFORE the new character is added to the textfield's string, your full text should be `textField.text`+`string` if im not wrong

Comment: Ok let me check .
I will let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shouldChangeCharactersIn` will get called prior to getting the actual text in the `UITextField`

This is how you get the full text from that `UITextField`

```
let newString = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
```

**Edit**

this is how you can use it

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == pinCode
    {
        guard let text = textField.text else { return  true }

        let newString = NSString(string: textField.text!).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let newLength = newString.characters.count

        if(5 >= newLength)
        {
            print(newLength)
        }

        else
        {
            if newLength == 6
            {
                serverValidation()

                print(newString)
                setFields(city: "Ajmer", state: "Rajasthan", country: "India")
                return newLength <= 6
            }
            else
            {
                 return newLength <= 6
            }
        }

    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer check

Comment: Thank you so much :-)
Save my day.

Answer (score 1):

Use **TextField** delegates method for this.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

 let currentCharacterCount = textField.text?.characters.count ?? 0
            if (range.length + range.location > currentCharacterCount+1)
            {
                return false
            }

            print(currentCharacterCount)
            let newLength = currentCharacterCount + string.characters.count - range.length
            return newLength <= 6 //this will not allow you to enter more than 6 characters 

}
```

After that  call

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
 {
             print(textField.text!)
            setFields(city: "Ajmer", state: "Rajasthan", country: "India")
}
```

to call this method  you can use         `view.endEditing(true)` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should get `newlength` from `textfield.text.length` + `string.length`

then get the text from `textfield.text` + `string`.

You can't get new text from `textfield.text` before call return true.

Comment: For new length you mean I have to do like this :-                                                         
 let newLength = textField.text.length + string.length

Comment: Yes. It works? I works on Objective C, so I can't translate it to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

if textField == pinCode
{
    guard let text = textField.text else { return  true }

    var txtAfterUpdate:NSString = textField.text! as NSString
    txtAfterUpdate = txtAfterUpdate.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    let txtString = txtAfterUpdate as String

    let newLength = txtString.characters.count
    if(5 >= newLength)
    {
        print(newLength)
    }

    else
    {
        if newLength == 6
        {
            print(textField.text!)
            setFields(city: "Ajmer", state: "Rajasthan", country: "India")
            return newLength <= 6
        }
        else
        {
            return newLength <= 6
        }
    }

}

return true
}
```

Comment: I tried it.
It is giving the same result. I mean 5 character only if (newLength == 6)
Thanks